# OAuth Username and password flow, id URL endpoint accept almost every token

Tags: oauth2, authentication

I'm testing (in Postman) a basic username/password flow. I have created Managed App in Salesforce so I have all that I need to invoke token endpoint and get an access token:

[image: The first call to the token endpoint]

So far so good. The process will return me an `access_token` and some infos about it.
As far as I know the `id` URL should be used to

- get extra info about user,
- identify the user,

So I invoke the identity URL for the first time and I get (as I suppose) `missingOAuthToken`. Then I set `Authorization` header with value `Bearer <access_token>`, and now it works.

The strange things happen now: if I modify the access token, putting randomly char, altering the cahracters lenght when I send the request I'm still authorized. Why this happens? This would be too strange, and since I'm not into Salesforce, I'm probably missing something.

Comment: Are you sure that the modified value is passed to salesforce? Can you try to extract some data with this access token?

Comment: Absolutely. Furthermore Postman automatically sends no-cache header

Comment: I have always had a problem using Postman, try www.onlinecurl.com or www.hurl.it and see if you have the same issue?
Also, could you please try the same thing while making a request via salesforce itself? It might not work in some other cases.